# django-celery Queuing and retrieving of result

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

We use django-celery for application. I have doubt regarding the workflow that we follow.

Currently when a user clicks on a link a task is queued using following code

```
result=retrieveDatausingWorker.apply_async(args=[type,dictParamList])
```

then the view return a page which shows a wait message to the user.This page also returns task_id of the current task  Then using an ajax call which sends the task id to the server i'm checking the status of the currently queued task.

code

```
def getDocketDownloaderWorkerStatus(request):

 if request.method=="POST":         

     task_id=request.POST.get('task_id')
     result = AsyncResult(task_id)
     if result:
         state, retval = result.state, result.result
         response_data = dict(id=task_id, status=state, result=safe_str(retval))            

     if (state=='SUCCESS' or state=='FAILURE') and ('task_id' in request.session):
         del request.session['task_id']             
     return HttpResponse(serialize(response_data), mimetype="application/json")
```

This ajax function will be called in every 5 seconds till server returns status=='SUCCESS' along with result.

Is this the right way. Or is it expensive to use `result = AsyncResult(task_id)`

I'm using database as my broker. The database is hosted in xeround cloud database.
When ever i run a worker CPU usage shoots pass 95% and we receive critical error message regarding this.

Comment: The issue seems resolved with help of WoLpH and Tommaso Barbugli.I have followed tutorials in this link http://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2012/feb/04/getting-started-celery-and-django/ Incase someone facing same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the correct method of checking, using the database as a broker is not really recommended however.

I would recommend switching to either Redis or RabbitMQ (RabbitMQ is probably overkill for your case). That should reduce the cpu usage a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Thinking of using Redis And i believe that to use redis i just have change the BROKER URL to something like BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0', after installing Redis right ?

Comment: Is there any tutorial for this ? I just installed  pip install -U django-celery-with-redis. But not sure where will i the get the URL?

Comment: @OptimusPrime celery supports redis as message broker (via the kombu library) so you just need to change the BROKER_URL to something like redis://HOST:PORT/DB_NUM in your settings

Comment: Optimus Prime: it's fairly easy to use Redis with Celery, here's the official documentation: http://celery.github.com/celery/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#broker-redis But it's basically as @TommasoBarbugli says :)

Comment: @WoLpH Thanks i have used redis instead of redis. And I see a drop in the cpu usage.Looks good in our initial testing... Thanks again for the great support ...